# Is it possible to overload insertion operator>> to take in user input without using arrays?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have written a program that takes input from users and adds integers together (can be very large). My program runs perfectly fine I have managed to make it accomplish the purpose I want it to. But was wondering if it was possible to overload operator>> (this takes in input from the user) without treating the input as an array.

```
std::istream& operator>> (std::istream& ins, test& t) {
    string num;
    int a;
    ins >> num;
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++) {
        a = num[i] - '0'; //Here clearly I'm treating the string as an array is it
                          //possible to do this without treating it like an array?
        t.append(a);
    }
    return ins;
}
```

Comment: No, not really. It *is* an array of characters. You can hide the `for` loop behind a call to some function from [`<algorithm>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) header, for example.

Comment: Can you show the `append()` method please?

Comment: Is there some reason that you don't just use algorithms?  You are using std::string so clearly you have no restrictions that prevent the use of the STL.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string

Comment: You might want to take a look at this too.  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istreams-remember-bad-state.html  I realize that it wasn't part of your question but I see a potential problem here with the '\n', and I don't see the rest of the program to know if that is a potential problem.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is not an array, but a container around a dynamic string (which is technically an array). The use of `operator[]` is needed to access each character, so you're doing nothing wrong there.

If you don't want to treat it as an array, you can use `std::for_each()` with a predicate like this:

```c++
std::for_each(std::begin(num), std::end(num),
              [] (char c) { test.append(c - '0'); });
```

You can also take input using a stream iterator like this:

```
std::for_each(std::istream_iterator<char>(ins),
              std::istream_iterator<char>(),
              [] (char c) { test.append(c - '0'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, here you don't have to treat numbers as string, which I assume your doing in your code.

```
template<typename T>
std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, std::vector<T>& v )
{
   std::string str;
   std::getline(is, str ) ;

   std::stringstream ss(str);
   T x;
   while ( ss >> x )
   {
     v.push_back( x );
   }

   return is;
}

int main() 
{
   std::vector <int> v;

   std::cin >>v;

   for(const auto &i:v)
     std::cout << i<< " " ;

   return 0;
}
```